# Updating database based on certain ID

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have a table within my database containing subscriptions, each subscription has a name, id and a notes column.

I'm trying to allow the user to update the notes column through a text area on the webpage. All of the subscriptions are in a list on the page which allows the user to click on them to view that specific subscription.

How would I make sure the note that is updated is correct with the id of the subscription they have clicked on?

I currently have this code.

```
<form method="POST" action="noteAction.php">
  <textarea id="notes" name="noteValue">$notes</texarea>
  <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

This is what I think my noteAction.php should look like however I cannot get it working.

```
    mysql_connect ("host", "user", "password") or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db("database_name") or die ('Data error:' . mysql_error());

    $text = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['noteValue']); 
    $query="UPDATE `subscription` SET `notes`= '$text' WHERE `id` = '$id'";

    mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating database ' . mysql_error());
```

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Where are you getting `$id` from?

Comment: I'm not, I just think that's how the query should look? However I am unsure on how to query the id to make it work.

Comment: Send the ID with the form, I'm guessing you are getting the `$notes` data from somewhere, send the ID along there. I'd recommend you find a tutorial / guide on forms and mysql / php, it's fairly simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use hidden element to store your id inside it.

```
 <form method="POST" action="noteAction.php">
   <textarea id="notes" name="noteValue">$notes</texarea>
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="id" value="your id goes here" /> 
   <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
 </form>
```

Comment: Thank you I never thought to use a hidden element to pass the id through, managed to fix the issue!

Answer (score 1):

When you're putting the note in the form, you must have an id for that note kicking about somewhere, after you retrieved it from the database. If you only selected the note contents in that query, select the ID as well. Then pass the ID over in a hidden field, and you have the ID to use in the MySQL query (which is correct).

```
<input type="hidden" name="note-id" value="note_id_here">
```